# VBoxManage add shared folder only if it doesn't exist?

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using Vagrant with Virtualbox. I'm configuring a sharedfolder in my Vagrant file. However, I get an error when trying to `vagrant up` the VM if the shared folder has already been created.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", "vagrant", "--hostpath", (("//?/" + File.dirname(__FILE__)).gsub("/","\\"))]
  v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
end

config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mkdir -p /vagrant", run: "always"
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant", run: "always"
```

So in this Vagrantfile, you can see I create the shared folder using Virtualbox's `VBoxManage` commands. But if I create the VM, boot it up, then shut it down, then `vagrant up` again, then it tries to create the shared folder again, but it already exists and therefore Vagrant throws an error.

Is it possible to tell if a shared folder already exists? Or is it possible to only create the shared folder during the first provision?

Note: the only reason I'm creating the shared folder manually like this (as opposed to using Vagrants shared folder command) is because there is a bug in Vagrant with Windows hosts that limits folder paths within the shared folder to be 260 characters long. The above manual shared folder setup bypasses this problem using UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line before adding shared folder. basically it kills the shared folder and creates it again during every run of VM

```
v.customize ["sharedfolder", "remove", :id, "--name", "vagrant"]
```